# OpenBSD httpd bottle app and uwsgi

Tags: apache, uwsgi, bottle, openbsd

I want to develope and deploy bottle apps on OpenBSD using the native httpd web server. From what I have found, the uWSGI will run the bottle app and the httpd will proxy the request. I do not follow how uWSGI gets started nor how to use the ini file on OpenBSD.

I can start the httpd and serve static content and my bottle app works fine with the development web server and pythonanywhere. Now I need to run it using httpd and uwsgi. How do I start the uwsgi server?

```
httpd.conf
server "default" {
        listen on egress port 80

        location "/bottleapp/*" {
                fastcgi socket ":3031"
        }
}
types {
        text/css css ;
        text/html htm html ;
        text/txt txt ;
        image/gif gif ;
        image/jpeg jpg jpeg ;
        image/png png ;
        application/javascript js ;
        application/xml xml ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a uwsgi rc.d file to be placed in /etc/rc.d. Something like the following might work:

```
#!/bin/sh

daemon="/path/to/uwsgi"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_reload="NO"

rc_stop() {
        ${daemon} --stop /path/to/uwsgi.pid
}

rc_cmd $1
```

Then you can run: rcctl enable uwsgi

And: rcctl set uwsgi flags "--ini /path/to/uwsgi.ini"

With the correct paths to the uwsgi ini file, binary, and pid file.